# EmberJS: clear data store and repopulate it

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Here's the deal: I'm trying to get the data from a php script, create javascript objects and assign them to ember data store, then call ember find() function to display the data.

Data Store:

```
    App.Images = DS.Model.extend({
        name: DS.attr('string'),
        imageThumb: DS.attr('string'),
        imageFull: DS.attr('string'),
    });

    //Have to do this, otherwise it doesn't work
    App.Images.FIXTURES = [];
```

Here comes the main function, that loads the data...
First of all, I'm not even sure if this is the correct way. It does work, however, but... I'm having serious doubts if it's supposed to be like that.
Mind the comment before calling the $.each function!

```
    App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
        model: function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "dataDao.php?f=getAll",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(data){ 

                    //I WANT TO CALL THE 'CLEAR DATA STORE' HERE!

                    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, value) {
                        App.Images.createRecord( 
                        {
                                id: value['id'],
                                name: value['name'],
                                imageThumb: value['imageThumb'],
                                imageFull: value['imageFull'],
                        }); 
                    });
                },
                error: function(err){
                  alert('error!' + JSON.stringify(err));
                }
            });
            return App.Images.find();
        }
    });
```

So, firstly, I'm not even sure if this is how ember is suppose to be used.

Secondly, isn't ajax suppose to be asynchronous? How come it waits for the success function to finish before calling return App.Images.find()? Shouldn't the return be called before the success function even finishes and the display should be empty?

Thirdly (and finally): how do I clear the data store before creating new objects? My results duplicate or rather, I keep adding same stuff to the existing data store otherwise.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're not using ember data, right?. POST method is supposed to be used for sending data to the sever, you should be using GET, and consider using Ember.$.getJSON("dataDao.php?f=getAll", function(json) {store.loadMany(App.Image, json)}). you can access the store before going into that method like this var store = this.get('store'). And if you notice, I'm using loadMany, not creating Images, I think after you do a store.commit, ember will send those images to the server, and it will try to do a POST to create the images(I think)

Comment: btw, in order for ember to map the values form you json properly, they need to be like this 'image_thumb' 'image_full', that way ember will map it to 'imageThumb' and 'imageFull'

Comment: Thank you, this does the job! Additional question, which method would I use if I wanted to post a JSON object TO THE server? With Ember.$.getJSON I get the data, but I want to have an additional function to post the data to the server, too.

Comment: to save a record ? var yourRecord = App.Image.find(1), then yourRecord.save(), or do a commit in your store, store.commit()

Comment: no, no, I'm familiar with that and it works.. I was talking about calling a php script to save the data. Currently, this is how I've implemented it:  `App.CreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   saveToServer: function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dataDao.php?f=addTo",
            data: JSON.stringify({id:1, data: "some data"}),
            success: function(status){ 
                alert(status);
            }
        });
   }
  });`

Comment: that's the way to do it, you're doing it right, and the way you were doing the GET request was also fine. If you want to do it in a better way, you can wrap that in a class, take a look here https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/mixins/ajax.js#L71, and https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse.js

Comment: btw, it might be possible that you didn't notice this, but getJSON is jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/